# Artifact not getting deployed in JFrog Articatory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-plugin

The artifact is not getting deployed in the artifactory.

The console logs are shown as below:

```
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) artifact = com.example.maven-samples:single-module-project:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) attachedArtifacts = []
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) offline = false
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) packaging = jar
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) pomFile = /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-job/maven-samples/single-module/pom.xml
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) project = MavenProject: com.example.maven-samples:single-module-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-job/maven-samples/single-module/pom.xml
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) skip = true
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager -   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[BuilderThread 0] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipsePluginManager - -- end configuration --
[BuilderThread 0] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo - Skipping artifact deployment
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Build Info Recorder: deploy artifacts: false
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Build Info Recorder: publication fork count: 1
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Build Info Recorder: publish build info: false
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Build Info Recorder: exportFile = null
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: Saving Build Info to '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-job/maven-samples/single-module/target/build-info.json'
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: deploy artifacts set to false, artifacts will not be deployed...
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: publish build info set to false, build info will not be published...
```

**My `pom.xml` looks as below:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.maven-samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>single-module-project</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>A Single Maven Module</name>
  <description>Sample single module Maven project with a working, deployable site.</description>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>utf-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>local-release</id>
      <name>Artifactory Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://192.168.106.144:8082/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>snapshots-local</id>
      <name>Artifactory Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://192.168.106.144:8082/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>local-release</id>
      <name>Artifactory Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://192.168.106.144:8082/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots-local</id>
      <name>Artifactory Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://192.168.106.144:8082/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
      <plugin>  
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->  
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>  
                <archive>  
                    <manifest>  
                        <mainClass>com.example.Greeter</mainClass>  
                    </manifest>  
                </archive>  
            </configuration>  
        </plugin> 

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.15.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.46.v20220331</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0.3</maven>
  </prerequisites>

</project>
```

Comment: Which maven goal you are calling

Comment: `MAVEN_GOAL = 'clean deploy -X -s maven-samples/single-module/settings_ci.xml'`

Comment: I was able to push earlier a few days ago. I am not able to figure out what has changed which is causing `skip = true`

Comment: I have added a few more console logs.